# Python excel dataset transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am reading excel data columns **Item, Month** and **value**

`Items = pd.read_excel('items_dataset.xlsx')`

```
Item       Date       value
All items   2021-04  100
All items   2021-05  100.2
All items   2021-06  99.7
Apples     2021-04   100
Apples    2021-05    100.1
Apples    2021-06    100.3
```

I am trying to switch columns and rows to create a new csv file.
I can aggregate data by **Date** and **Item** column

`Items.groupby(['Date','Item']).agg({"value": lambda x:(x)})`

The end result should be :
First column should become **Date**, data in **Item** row should become a columns headings and their respected values in **Index value...** should appear

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.pivot(
    index="Date", columns="Item", values="Index value (April 2021 = 100)"
).reset_index()
df.columns.name, df.index.name = None, None

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Date  All items  Apples  Baked beans
0  2021-04      100.0   100.0        100.0
1  2021-05      100.2   100.1        100.0
2  2021-06       99.7   100.3        100.0
3  2021-07      100.0    99.6        100.1
4  2021-08      100.9   101.2        101.4
5  2021-09       99.5    88.6        101.4
6  2021-10      103.4    99.3        106.1
7  2021-11      103.2    93.5        111.6
8  2021-12      104.9    97.6        112.0
9  2022-01      105.6    99.4        115.1
```